# How to create a Facebook App with "Like it" confirmation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, confirmation

i'm a totally *newbie* in Facebook App coding and i would like to creat a simple app that give the main content only after a "Like it" confirmation?

The example:
http://www.facebook.com/RelapseRecords?ref=ts&sk=app_162097493835692

(You only see the download links after "Like it")

Where i can find a how-to for that?

Thanks in advise, reevex

Comment: I might be wrong, but as i understand it this is not possible with I-Frame but only with FBNL (which has been discontinued)

Comment: @fingerman,

thank you for your answer.

Hmm, Facebook writes...
"We are in the process of deprecating FBML. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS"

Nice, but how can i make this?...
> Show main content only _after_ a "Like it" confirmation.

I have no idea how i can check if "Like it" Button is active in any way!?

thank, reevex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is possible. Facebook recently introduced the „[Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)” parameter which can be used to obtain what you need. After you decode this parameter you will have a JSON object. One of its field is called `page`. This is another JSON object containing among other params the `liked` boolean if the user has liked the page. This is only available if your app is an iframe loaded in a Page tab.

Based on this boolean value you can choose which content to display to the user.

Good luck!

Comment: Ahh, i understand that correct: i can do this "liked" check direct in php? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth ... my Iframe loads a php file, in that i check the signed-request and "if liked=true" my content output is B else A?

Comment: yes, it is meant to be used in your php script, and yes, based on that you know which content to output